# Why does Maxima say these expressions are not equivalent?

Tags: maxima-software

If I compare two expressions in Maxima, it tells me they are equivalent, as expected:

```
(%i25) is(equal( sqrt(2)*sqrt(5), sqrt(10) ));
(%o25)                               true
```

But if I multiply each expression by a constant, it then tells me they're not equivalent any more:

```
(%i26) is(equal( sqrt(2)*sqrt(5)*2, sqrt(10)*2 ));
(%o26)                               false
```

Surely they must still be equivalent if I do the same thing to both expressions? If I try adding a constant instead of multiplying, it returns true as expected:

```
(%i27) is(equal( sqrt(2)*sqrt(5)+2, sqrt(10)+2 ));
(%o27)                               true
```

version info

```
(%i2) build_info(); 
(%o2) Maxima version: "5.32.1" 
      Maxima build date: "2014-01-10 01:52:55" 
      Host type: "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" 
      Lisp implementation type: "GNU Common Lisp (GCL)" 
      Lisp implementation version: "GCL 2.6.10"
```

Comment: Answer is  very simple,It's a bug in software.

Comment: Is Maxima doing these symbolically or numerically? Clearly $2 \sqrt 2 \sqrt 5 = 2 \sqrt{10}$, but $2 \times 1.4142 \times 2.236 \neq 2 \times 3.1623$. It would have more numerical precision, but the discrepancy might be enough to cause problems.

Comment: @DavidR. I'm not sure. Symbolic calculations are kind of the point of Maxima (I thought) but I've noticed that it returns "unknown" if I do it like this:

 is(equal( sqrt(a)*sqrt(b), sqrt(a*b) ));

Comment: Relevant [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30315) on implementation (coding) problem.

Comment: @JohnB Maxima is doing this symbollically but I think `unknown` is the correct output to `is(equal( sqrt(a)*sqrt(b), sqrt(a*b) ));` unless you set `radexpand=all` or `assume(a>0)` or `assume(b>0)` I think this is simply a bug

Comment: @DavidR. Maxim uses symbolic computation here.

Comment: @JohnB can you post the result of build_info();

Comment: @miracle173 here you go:

(%i2) build_info();
(%o2) 
Maxima version: "5.32.1"
Maxima build date: "2014-01-10 01:52:55"
Host type: "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
Lisp implementation type: "GNU Common Lisp (GCL)"
Lisp implementation version: "GCL 2.6.10"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly enough

```
is(equal( sqrt(2)*sqrt(5)*7, sqrt(10)*7 ));
```

will evaluate to true as will

```
is(equal( sqrt(2)*sqrt(5)*c, sqrt(10)*c ));
```

`is(equal(a,b))` tries to simplify a-b and gives true when a-b equals zero.
Problem with $\sqrt{2}*\sqrt{5}*2$ is that it simplifies to
$ 2^\frac{3}{2} \sqrt{5} $ which then confuses maxima (obviously a bug)